# What do the dashed lines separate in the debug navigator?

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

Looking at:

[image]

I can't understand why are things grouped together between dashed lines.

<sub>I cropped the screenshot to remove method named I didn't want to share. But this screenshot is entirely from `Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)`</sub>

I already thought of the following three but all seem to be incorrect.

- It's separated by classes. Not true: different classes were on the same side of dashed lines.
- It's separated by directories. Not true: files that were both in `RxSwift` directory were on different side of a dashed line.
- It's separated by modules. Not true: files from a pod and my own code were on the same side of a dashed line.

I also looked at: [Examine threads and stacks in the Debug navigator](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devea99126aa)
 but didn't find information on how they're grouped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Got this answer from a senior dev named Daniel Kennett on Slack.</sub>

There are lines here that are *collapsed* (look at the numbers)
new messages

You can click a button down in the filter field at the bottom to have it *expand* the missing lines in the trace